# Force to run catch on Observable.fromPromise

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ionic3

I have a service layer method like below. I need to test (just a manual test and 
 I'm not using any testing framework here) the `catch` method on it. So how can I force to run `catch` statement always? I just need to simulate the `401` error.

```
 get(api) {
        let header = new Headers();
        return Observable.fromPromise(this.createHeader(header))
            .map(() => {
                let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
                options.withCredentials = true;
                options.headers = header;
                return options
            })
            .switchMap((options) => this.http.get(api, options))
            .catch((err: Error | Response) => {
                if (err instanceof Response && err.status === 401) {// I need to test this.
                    // handle 401
                    console.log('get error');
                }
                return Observable.throw(err);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Couldnt you provide a mock for the createHeader method and in your mocked version throw?

Comment: It would be great if you can explain it using `code snippet` and in the answer section? @cgatian

Comment: When you say manual test, what do you mean?

Comment: I'm not using any test framework here.I just need to simulate the `401` error here when I run the app. Then I can test the code which I'll write inside the  `if (err instanceof Response && err.status === 401)` block. @cgatian

Comment: You can mock `http.get` yourself to return an error (`Observable.throw(error)`) or you can use [Angular's MockBackend](https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend)